# req.body is empty on POST with data, however logging req shows req.body exists

Tags: node.js, express, post

### My problem

I am trying to write a register/login page in node.js using express.js. I have decided to split routes and app initialization into two files. When I send a POST request to `localhost:3000/register` with the data `{"username":"xyz","password":"xyz"}`, the request object has the attribute body. However when I try to access this attribute, I get undefined.

### My current code

```
// app.js
// Load express and define port
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;
// App Configurations
app.use(express.json())
// Load Routes
var registerRouter = require('./controllers/register.js');
// Use Routes
app.use('/register', registerRouter);
// Start App
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`));
```

```
// controllers/register.js
// requires
var argon2i = require('argon2-ffi').argon2i;
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var {Database, Model} = require('mongorito');
var crypto = require('crypto')
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var randomBytes = Promise.promisify(crypto.randomBytes);
var express = require('express');
// define router
var router = express.Router();
// Mongo Connection
const db = new Database('localhost/test', { 
    reconnectTries: 5 
});
// Models
class User extends Model {}
// Register Models
db.register(User);
// Routes
router.post('/', async (res, req) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    if(!req.body) return req.sendStatus(400); 
    const username = req.body.username;
    const salt = randomBytes(32); 
    const password = argon2i.hash(req.body.password, salt);
    var user = new User({
        username: username,
        password: password,
        salt: salt
    });
    await user.save;
    res.send("User Created");
});
// Disconnect From Database
db.disconnect;
//export router
module.exports = router;
```

### My expected result

I expect to be able to access `req.body` and `req.body.username`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a small issue in you code.  The `router.post` callback function first parameter is `req` and the second is `res`. The `Callback function` parameters are fixed not named parameters.

You are trying to get the body on the `response object`, though the name of the parameter is `req` but it still holds the `response object`. which is causing the issue.

Please change it.

**Wrong:**

```
router.post('/', async (res, req) => {
```

**Correct:**

```
router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you are importing bodyParser in controller/register but not setting it, at least in this snippet. if you do not have any special reasons for putting it in the controller, then do this instead.

```
// app.js
// Load express and define port
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser'); // new code

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // new code
const port = 3000;
// App Configurations
app.use(express.json())
// Load Routes
var registerRouter = require('./controllers/register.js');
// Use Routes
app.use('/register', registerRouter);
// Start App
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`));
```